# How I turn on a vpn(ikev2) on ios in Swift, that was manually configured

Tags: ios, swift, vpn

I need to manage (turn on/off) a ikev2 vpn that was already configured(with certificate) manually on iOS. I need to do that in Swift. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Share some code what you've done.

Comment: A quick google of this very thing reveals the Network Extension library by apple... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension You should take these steps yourself before asking on SO.

Comment: No code, yet. I tried to start vpn that was configured outside the app(manually by installing certificates via safari) but seems I can't start a vpn that wasn't configured in app.

Comment: Also I am afraid that you don't understand the question(or you answer without knowing what is about). Like I said the VPN was configured MANUALLY not by the app. In this case I am not sure that apple allow you to start/stop vpn that was not configured by your app

Comment: That's a little toxic, I was merely making a point that as per the SO asking guidelines, an asker should include steps they have already taken in their question, else how am I to know that you've already tried that. Furthermore, you may look at my many other well received and helpful answers to see that it is fact not the case.

Answer (score -2):

There is a method which you can use to start your vpn.

```
NEVPNManager.sharedManager().startVPNTunnel()
```